# How to manage updates for a custom WordPress plugin hosted in a GitHub repository

Tags: wordpress

## Background

- I'm a WordPress plugin developer.
- I've developed a plugin that's hosted on GitHub, not on wordpress.org.
- The review period on wordpress.org is excessively lengthy.

## Problem

- I need a method to notify users about new versions of my plugin.
- Could you recommend any SaaS services or plugins that offer this functionality?
- Alternatively, if I were to develop it myself, how could I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use shell script to check version

Answer (score 1):

@joachim-kudish developed a solution for this in 2011: https://github.com/radishconcepts/WordPress-GitHub-Plugin-Updater

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Git Updater, It's been around for a long time. It has great support and is something I use myself.

https://git-updater.com/

It works with WordPress and will show your plugin has an update inside the WP dashboard based on the version number.